# PDE book recommendation(especially about non-homogeneous BCs)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

My question has already been asked in this site but I want to make an effort and explain what exactly I want from that PDE book, since no book that I looked at(at least from their contents) is satisfying for me.

Well, I took a class in my university which was a combination of ODE and PDE. Because of the great content that we had to cover in one semester, it is obvious that the lessons couldn't have been with more detail. As far as the topics we covered in PDEs, we talked about Sturm-Liouville problems(the simple ones) and we solved PDEs with homogeneous BCs using separation of variables. We made a little reference on how to solve PDEs with non-homogeneous BCs, but we only saw very specific and simple cases(which many books also do).

What I look is a book that completely covers linear PDEs, as long as Sturm-Liouville problems, and not emphasizing on homogeneous cases(either regarding the BCs or the PDE itself), if possible with some mathematical rigor. The reason I want that is that I attend a lesson about physics of vibrations and there are many non-homogeneous PDEs that appear when solving the wave-equation.

Thanks for any recommendations in advance!

P.S.: As you see, my whole concern is about non-homogeneous BCs. If there are any online-sources that are related to this topic, please copy it and paste it as an alternative to bying a whole book.

Comment: You might start with [a pretty inexpensive](https://www.amazon.com/Applications-Greens-Functions-Science-Engineering/dp/0486797961/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=green+functions&qid=1617059716&s=books&sr=1-1) guide to the use of Green's functions. Oops, my mistake, you're asking about boundary conditions. In that case any good book on potential theory will introduce the use of single- and double-layer potentials, probably a good stepping stone to parabolic and hyperbolic systems.

Comment: Standard PDEs books should discuss how to handle non-homogeneous boundary conditions. I haven't checked, but I bet it's discussed in Strauss for example.

Comment: @littleO PDE book of Strauss is worth of bying?

Comment: @Aruralreader Do you have any such book in your mind?

Comment: Kellogg's Foundations of Potential Theory is a favorite.